# Team foundation Server web Access menu bar customization by adding new custom Tab

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS as our repository, and i work on building the TFS server side plugins and any customization related to Team Foundation Server. Here i am trying to add an custom tab in the Kanabn board, as highlighted below are the default inbuilt tabs, in the same way i want add an custom tab. Can some one point me the direction from where can i start this ?

[image: Web Access]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start to custom a Hub(Tab) in TFS, follow the steps in this document: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node

In  the "contributions" of the Manifest file, “targets” should be "ms.vss-web.project-hub-groups-collection" if you want to add a Hub at the Menb bar. Here is my example of the Manifest file:

```
{
  "manifestVersion": 1,
  "id": "samples-contributions-guide",
  "version": "0.1.5",
  "name": "Tingting Hub Extension",
  "description": "**********",
  "publisher": "publisher",
  "categories": [
    "Developer samples"
  ],
  "links": {
    "learn": {
      "uri": "https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-extension-samples"
    }
  },
  "targets": [
    {
      "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
    }
  ],
  "branding": {
    "color": "rgb(190, 39, 3)",
    "theme": "dark"
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "path": "hello-world.html",
      "addressable": true
    },
    {
      "path": "SDK/scripts",
      "addressable": true
    }
  ],
  "contributions": [
    {
      "id": "project-hub-group",
      "type": "ms.vss-web.hub-group",
      "description": "Adds a hub group at the project/team-level",
      "targets": [
        "ms.vss-web.project-hub-groups-collection"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "Hub1",
        "order": 100
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "project-hub-group-hub",
      "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
      "description": "Adds a hub to the contributed project-level hub group",
      "targets": [
        ".project-hub-group"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "Hub1-1",
        "order": 100,
        "uri": " hello-world.html"
      }
    }
 ]
}
```

To know more about TFS Extensions, here is some examples.https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples

Comment: Hi Ting , Thank you for your reply , will this also work for "on premise" TFS 15 ?